# How to configure a management IP address on a router on a stick?

Tags: routing, cisco, router

I'm setting up a simple Router on a stick following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_xpsk-uRug&t=338s) The actual routing part works fine, however, I'm struggling to assign the router a management IP address.

The current router (Cisco 1841) configuration is:

```
 - interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!

 - interface FastEthernet0/0.100
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.0.100.1 255.255.255.0
!

 - interface FastEthernet0/0.150
 encapsulation dot1Q 150
 ip address 10.0.150.1 255.255.255.0
!

 - interface FastEthernet0/0.200
 encapsulation dot1Q 200
 ip address 10.0.200.1 255.255.255.0
! 
 - interface FastEthernet0/0.201
 encapsulation dot1Q 201
 ip address 10.0.201.1 255.255.255.0
!

 - interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
```

I've tried SSHing to `10.0.100.1` - no luck

I've tried:

```
interface fa0/0
ip address 10.0.100.11 255.255.255.0
```

returns an error:

> IP overlaps with FA0/0.100.

Also tried using:

```
VLAN 100
IP address 10.0.100.11 255.255.255.0
```

This just isn't a valid command.

kind regards

Comment: I think you're trying to use a non management Vlan as the management Vlan, and "interface fa0/0 ip address 10.0.100.11 255.255.255.0" is trying to establish an IP address on a interface on which you've already established sub interfaces.

Comment: Thanks Davidw. 
Is there a specific command or keyword to define a VLAN as being a management VLAN?

Comment: Arcass, try "description Management VLAN 100" on the FA0/0.100 subinterface.